# Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' (causes app to crash)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working through a tutorial that I found online and received the issue:

> Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int'

I have looked through some of the other post and haven't found one that helped me yet. I am new to programming and I would greatly appreciate any helpful advice!

This is the part where I  am getting the issue:

```
- (void)handleTouchAtLocation:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
    if (!self.editable) return;

    int newRating = 0;
    for(int i = self.imageViews.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [self.imageViews objectAtIndex:i];        
        if (touchLocation.x > imageView.frame.origin.x) {
            newRating = i+1;
            break;
        }
    }

    self.rating = newRating;
}
```

This is the top part of my .h file:

```
#import "RWTRateView.h"

@implementation RWTRateView

@synthesize notSelectedImage = _notSelectedImage;
@synthesize halfSelectedImage = _halfSelectedImage;
@synthesize fullSelectedImage = _fullSelectedImage;
@synthesize rating = _rating;
@synthesize editable = _editable;
@synthesize imageViews = _imageViews;
@synthesize maxRating = _maxRating;
@synthesize midMargin = _midMargin;
@synthesize leftMargin = _leftMargin;
@synthesize minImageSize = _minImageSize;
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

These are my property statements:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *notSelectedImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *halfSelectedImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *fullSelectedImage;
@property (assign, nonatomic) float rating;
@property (assign) BOOL editable;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray * imageViews;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int maxRating;
@property (assign) int midMargin;
@property (assign) int leftMargin;
@property (assign) CGSize minImageSize;
@property (assign) id <RWTRateViewDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: 1. You do not need the `@synthesize` statements. 2. You do need the `@property` statements, what are they? 3. When choosing a tutorial choose one that was created in thw last couple of years. 4. Where is the crash error message? 5. "Implicit conversion loses integer precision" is a  compiler message.

Comment: @zaph, I added the property statements in the question. Any good sites you could recommend for me to try out. I have just started learning objective-c since last week. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you rightly say, this is the problem:

```
for (int i = self.imageViews.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

The problem is that `self.imageViews.count` is *not* an int. It is an NSUInteger, which is a very different animal. Simply rewrite:

```
for (NSUInteger i = self.imageViews.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

In particular, this conversion can cause issues across the bitness barrier. An NSUInteger changes its size depending whether we are on 32-bit or 64-bit. But int does not. The two are not compatible.

Comment: The tutorial you are using was probably written before 64-bit existed, so it was careless on this point. I remember when I updated my code for 64-bit and I had a _lot_ of warnings just like yours, because I was making the same facile assumption.

Comment: Now it says comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true

Comment: Then change it to NSInteger instead... Sorry about that.